# UIButtonBarItem does not seem to fire selector

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am writing a simple iOS app in XCode 7.3, which I believe puts me using Swift 2.2.   I am trying to use a UIDatePicker with UIToolbar with a UITextfield, and for some reason I tapping on the Cancel button seems not to call the method datePickerCancelled on the controller. Everything displays fine(picker, buttons , etc.), but the event won't fire. I have tried several variations of adding the selector to the UIBarButtonItem, and nothing seems to work.  As you can see from the code this a pretty trivial case so it escapes why it should be this difficult.  Thank you.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        var datePickerToolbar = UIToolbar()
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton =  UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel, target: self, action: #selector(datePickerCancelled))
        let flexSpace =  UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)


        datePickerToolbar.setItems([cancelButton,flexSpace, doneButton], animated: true)
        datePicker.userInteractionEnabled = true
        cancelButton.enabled = true
        self.dateField.inputView = datePicker
        self.dateField.inputAccessoryView = datePickerToolbar
    }

    func datePickerCancelled(){
        self.datePicker.resignFirstResponder();

    }`  I
```

Comment: As Matt pointed out, I failed to set the height of my toolbar.  Even though I could see the buttons just fine above the picker, it still failed to call the event handler.  Adding the following code fixed my issue    self.datePickerToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
var datePickerToolbar = UIToolbar()
```

This results in a toolbar of zero size. The Cancel button is visible, but it is outside of its superview, namely the toolbar — because the toolbar has zero size.

*A view outside of its superview cannot be tapped.*

You can easily confirm this by setting the toolbar's `clipsToBounds` to `true` and running the app. The Cancel button will now be invisible, because things outside the toolbar are no longer shown.

---

If the event *did* fire, your `datePickerCancelled` function still wouldn't *do* anything:

```
func datePickerCancelled(){
    self.datePicker.resignFirstResponder();
}
```

Your date picker was never first responder, so that line wouldn't cause anything to happen.

Perhaps you meant this:

```
func datePickerCancelled(){
    self.dateField.resignFirstResponder();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, I am aware of the debugger, and I put a breakpoint on self.dateField.resignFirstResponder(). and It never gets that far.  That's why I can safely make such a claim.

Comment: Agreed.  Still doesn't answer my question, but you are correct.

Comment: Awesome!!  That worked.  Thank you so much.  See you don't have to be so terse about it.  Remember we all start somewhere, and a little patient with those us who are not as experienced as yourself can go a long way.

Comment: I don't agree. You asked the question poorly and said "does not _seem_ to fire selector", as if you were uncertain. I think I was quite right to push for proof and certainty. Moreover, as I also pointed out, your code would not have worked in any case. Had I not pushed back on both these points, we would not have been led to the correct answer. That is the scientific method.

Comment: Agree to disagree.  Just try and avoid exclamation points in the future.  You come off as obnoxious jerk.

Comment: I _am_ an obnoxious jerk. But I'm also right about what was wrong with your code. :)